# plaid development redirect uri?

Tags: plaid

I would like to test some real data with plaid and that's why i am using development environment now instead of sandbox. And I am confused what redirect uri should i use.
This is the error on my localhost:3000.

> Unable to fetch link_token: please make sure your backend server is running and that your .env file has been configured correctly.
> Error Code: INVALID_FIELD
> Error Type: INVALID_REQUEST
> Error Message: redirect_uri must use HTTPS

I understand that for development envrionment we should use https instead of http, but I wonder what uri should i redirect to if i am only testing the API?

Thank you

Comment: The .env file is attached here:
PLAID_CLIENT_ID=xxxx 
PLAID_SECRET=xxxxx
PLAID_ENV=development
PLAID_PRODUCTS=auth,transactions
PLAID_COUNTRY_CODES=FR
PLAID_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost:3000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't particularly care about using the Quickstart with OAuth redirect flows, and just want to use live data from Development, you should just be able to leave that field blank.

Comment: leaving it blank or removing the line completely doesn't change the error. it still doesn't work in development. still complains about a need to have https redirects.